# PHPmailer not delivering to certain addresses

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have yet another problem with PHPmailer (I hate it by now). The problem is that it sends properly only to one address, but I've tried two others and it doesn't work. It works only if "setFrom" id the same as "addAddress". Here is the script:

```
<?php 
if (array_key_exists('email', $_POST)) {
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Warsaw');

require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

$mail->isSMTP();                                    
$mail->Host = 'smtp.poczta.onet.pl';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;  
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                      
$mail->Username = 'myname@onet.pl'; 
$mail->Password = 'password';       
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port = 465;     

if ($mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'])) {
    $mail->Subject = 'Wiadomość z formularza kontaktowego';
$mail->setFrom('myname@onet.pl');
$mail->addAddress('myname@onet.pl');

$mail->isHTML(false);

$mail->Body = <<<EOT
Email: {$_POST['email']}
Imię: {$_POST['name']}
Wiadomość: {$_POST['message']}
EOT;

if (!$mail->send()) {
        $msg = 'Sorry, something went wrong. Please try again later.';
} else {
        $msg = 'Message sent! Thanks for contacting us.';
}
} else {
        $msg = 'Invalid email address, message ignored.';
    }
}
?>
```

If I change addAddress to

```
$mail->addAddress('myname@gmail.com');
```

Or

```
$mail->addAddress('myname@mydomain.pl');
```

I do not receive anything. Also

```
$mail->addAddress('myname@mydomain.pl');
$mail->addAddress('myname@gmail.com');
$mail->addAddress('myname@onet.pl');
```

Not working either. Why is that? What can be the problem? SMTPdebug return the same message each time, with 1 address or 3:

```
2017-01-31 12:09:32 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.poczta.onet.pl ESMTP 
2017-01-31 12:09:32 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO dobrywebdev.pl 
2017-01-31 12:09:32 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.poczta.onet.pl 250-PIPELINING 250-SIZE 90000000 250-ETRN 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN XOAUTH2 250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN XOAUTH2 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250 8BITMIME 
2017-01-31 12:09:32 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN 
2017-01-31 12:09:32 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 
2017-01-31 12:09:32 CLIENT -> SERVER: Z3JodUBvbmV0LnBs 
2017-01-31 12:09:32 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6 
2017-01-31 12:09:32 CLIENT -> SERVER: R3VwaWFzem1hdGEx 
2017-01-31 12:09:32 SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 2.7.0 Authentication successful 
2017-01-31 12:09:32 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM: 
2017-01-31 12:09:32 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.0 Ok 
2017-01-31 12:09:32 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO: 
2017-01-31 12:09:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.5 Ok 
2017-01-31 12:09:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO: 
2017-01-31 12:09:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.5 Ok 
2017-01-31 12:09:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO: 
2017-01-31 12:09:34 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.5 Ok 
2017-01-31 12:09:34 CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA 
2017-01-31 12:09:34 SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 End data with . 
2017-01-31 12:09:34 CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Tue, 31 Jan 2017 13:09:32 +0100 
2017-01-31 12:09:34 CLIENT -> SERVER: To: xxxxx@onet.pl, xxxxx@mydomain.pl, xxxxxx@gmail.com 
2017-01-31 12:09:34 CLIENT -> SERVER: From: xxxx@onet.pl 
2017-01-31 12:09:34 CLIENT -> SERVER: Reply-To: xxxxxx@gmail.com 
2017-01-31 12:09:34 CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: =?utf-8?Q?Wiadomo=C5=9B=C4=87_z_formularza_kontaktowego?= 
2017-01-31 12:09:34 CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <3095337e299e4acde25515b287e51756@xxxxxx.pl> 
2017-01-31 12:09:34 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.22 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) 
2017-01-31 12:09:34 CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0 
2017-01-31 12:09:34 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 
2017-01-31 12:09:34 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit 
2017-01-31 12:09:34 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2017-01-31 12:09:34 CLIENT -> SERVER: Email: xxxxx@gmail.com 
2017-01-31 12:09:34 CLIENT -> SERVER: Imię: xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx 
2017-01-31 12:09:34 CLIENT -> SERVER: Wiadomość: Cześć 
2017-01-31 12:09:34 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2017-01-31 12:09:34 CLIENT -> SERVER: . 
2017-01-31 12:09:34 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 3vCQ6j0vswzSv6lLW 
2017-01-31 12:09:34 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 
2017-01-31 12:09:34 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Bye
```

What might be the problem here? I could redirect all e-mails from that 1 address to another, but I don't want to do that. Is that server realted error or should I add something to the script?

Comment: Please format your log output properly, it's almost impossible to read as is.

Comment: My bad, now should be better.

Comment: I'm actually the same issue and have read through the documents in the ISP and can't find an answer.  Using DreamHost and just trying to send to Gmail addresses.  I can successfully send to addresses that match my domain.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that it sends properly only to one address, but I've tried two others and it doesn't work.

PHPMailer only prepares the email content then, depending how it is configured, it passes the email either to the PHP [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function or to a local MTA (usually `sendmail`) or to a remote SMTP server.

Either way, the email is eventually sent to a SMTP server that handles it. If the SMTP server hosts the destination account then it stores the mail, otherwise it passes it to the SMTP server that handles the Internet domain of the recipient's email address.

If some emails arrive at the destination while others do not arrive then PHPMailer is not the one to blame.

Different servers have different policies against SPAM and, if the email addresses of your recipients are valid, then the most probable cause of failure is the fact that these servers consider your mailing as SPAM. This happens especially when you try to send multiple emails in a short period of time.

You should talk to the system administrator of the SMTP server you use (the IT guy, if it's the company server and/or your ISP) about this issue. They could advise you what to put in the email headers to increase the chances of your emails being sent. Being informed about your intents they also can adjust the settings of the SMTP and DNS servers ([SPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework), [`DKIM`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail)) to mark the SMTP server as legitimate to send your emails.

Comment: I will conact my ISP then and see what they say. But I still don't understand why it works when I set FROM as 'xxxx@onet.pl' and TO as 'xxxx@onet.pl', but when I add another TO it doesn't.